# Getting facebook Contact data

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on an android application where I need to fetch login user data.
I need facebook login user detail like first name , last name , email address etc. I did google there are two ways to get user data one is using Json and one is using GraphUser , anyone can explain what is difference in both method to fetch the user data ?
What is the best method to use in an android application ?

Answer (score 0):

They both make the same underlying graph API requests to get the data. GraphUser gives you a strongly typed interface to get properties like firstName, lastName, etc, whereas otherwise you'd have to parse the JSON yourself.

If you're making an android app, I would recommend using the [Request.newMyFriendsRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#newMyFriendsRequest%28Session,%20GraphUserListCallback%29) which gives you a list of GraphUsers.